# FULL OUTER JOIN and like function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Following query works:

```
SELECT
  cat.category,
  exp.*
FROM
  `expenses` exp
join
  `categories` cat ON exp.Transaction like concat("%",cat.key,"%")
LIMIT
  1000
```

What I want to it do a full outer join so I can find all transactions without a cat.key.

I am currently getting following error message:

> FULL OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality
>   of fields from both sides of the join.

How can I solve this? I tried using "not like" but this not give what I want.

Comment: please provide your input set and desire output @christoph

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQury Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  MAX(IF(exp.Transaction LIKE CONCAT("%",cat.key,"%"), cat.category, NULL)) category,
  ANY_VALUE(EXP).*
FROM `project.dataset.expenses` `exp`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.categories` cat 
GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(`exp`)
LIMIT 1000
```

Try, it should work unless some specific details are missing in the question

Answer (score 0):

You want a `LEFT JOIN`.  I believe this should work in BigQuery:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*, 1 as dum
      FROM expenses e
     ) e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.*, 1 as dum
      FROM categories c
     ) c
     ON e.dum = c.dum AND
        e.Transaction like concat('%', c.key, '%)
WHERE c.key IS NULL
LIMIT 1000;
```

At least, similar queries work when I try them.

I will caution that this will not scale well.  So it might not work on your actual data.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join. > Thanks but I get this error when trying it.

Comment: @Christoph . . . This has an equality condition . . . one `dum`.  I even tested this on small data, so the syntax works.

Comment: okay thanks but for me I keep receiving that error. I tried it a second time.

Comment: @Christoph . . . I believe you.  Sometimes BigQuery only picks up absurdities on larger data sets.  That can make it harder to test alternatives.

Comment: I fixed it in my case using an UDF and calculating the values instead of joining them.